# Iteratively traverse through tree to find size

Tags: java, tree, iteration

I need to find the number of elements in a tree using an iterative algorithm, but I'm finding the code conceptually very difficult to write.

My approach is to start at the root node and visit the child nodes, then the children of these child nodes, and so on.

This is the code I've written which works for a small tree, but isn't a real solution because I'd need to add an additional block for each level of depth:

```
// Start the counter at 1 because the root node counts
int size = 1;

for(ITree child1 : root) {
    size++;
    for(ITree child2 : child1) {
        size++;
        for(ITree child3 : child2) {
            size++;
            for(ITree child4 : child3) {
                size++;
                for(ITree child5 : child4) {
                    size++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return size;
```

Comment: I think this is a similiar question to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547622/counting-nodes-in-a-tree-in-java perhaps you can find some answers there.

Comment: I was reading that earlier and it was helpful, but this tree isn't binary and I need to do it iteratively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conceptually, keep a stack (LinkedList, etc.).  For each child (now, your child loops), add to the stack.  Continue looping through the stack until it is finally empty.

This isn't tested, but this should do exactly what you're looking for.  I'm just using `java.io.File` instead of your "ITree", as it's something I can compile against:

```
int sizeOfTree(File root){
    // Start the counter at 1 because the root node counts

    int size = 1;

    LinkedList<File> stack = new LinkedList<File>();
    stack.add(root);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        File f = stack.remove();
        for(File child : f.listFiles()){
            size++;
            stack.add(child);
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: Using a LinkedList will provide the "iterative" traversal requested, rather than using recursion - which can lead to stack overflows.

Comment: still don't understand what's going on, but judging by the votes you're correct so thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept - but I'd like to help eliminate any confusion you have.  What can I elaborate on?

Comment: I'd be able to question every line of your code, so I'll question what I consider to be the main point - what is the stack storing and why?

Comment: By using a "stack" data structure, we're essentially storing information about the stack on the heap, instead of using recursion - which uses the JVM's internal stack.  The difference is that instead of holding on to only the remaining items to process (as in my example) - the JVM's stack holds on to all of the variables used in each call of the stack, etc.  So "recursion" is sometimes easier to setup, but an iterative approach will typically scale better.  In short - the "stack" list is storing information about items left to process, in order to prevent use of recursive function calls.

Comment: After implementing it in my solution and reading through line by line, it makes sense now! :D I think it was just the files that confused me. The above helped clarify it further, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Using a recursive data structure**

It is not practically possible to iteratively traverse a recursive data structure, like a tree with pointers - this is because of the fact that the objects "hide" their underlying data elements.

**Using a different data structure**

All trees can be stored/implemented as to linear, array data structures, where indices can be calculated using exponential mathematics :

For example, a tree [0, 1, 2, 3, null, 4,null] would describe a tree with 0 at the root, where 0 had direct children 1 and 2.  And then 1 has left child "3", and 2 has left child "4".

Thus, if you store the tree this way, the number of elements is, naturally, the number of non-null elements in the array.

Put more simply : Store the tree in a linear structure , and you can know the length at any given time without having to make any kind of fancy algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The key word for your task is recursion. Tree is a classical recursive structure, so you should write recursive method that accepts root nodes, counts size of this node and then calls itself for all children. Here is pseudo code:

```
public int getSize(ITree root) {
    return getSize(root, 0);
}

private int getSize(ITree node, int size) {
    size++;
    for(ITree child : node.children()) {
        size += getSize(child, size)
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: But that isn't just recursive, it's also iterative. Can I do it using only recursion? Or only iteration? (not both)

Comment: Please explain what do you mean when you say "interactive"